# how do I fix this infinite scroll problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, infinite-scroll, web-frontend

I am trying to make a social post section with infinite scroll, when I only render the posts everything works fine, until I added ad cards between regular cards. I am using both separate mock data(one for regular post and one for ad data). For now I have limited data sets so for the infinite scroll I am showing the same data over and over. But the **Problem** is when I added the Adcards, the infinite scroll isn't working and when I scroll down to the bottom it forcedly scrolling up and randomizing the posts. I did take help from gpt in this code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import mockData from "../../data/mockData/mockData";
import { PostCard } from "..";
import { Adcard } from "..";
import adData from "../../data/mockData/adData";
import Masonry from "react-masonry-css";
import "./foryou.css";

function Foryou() {
  const [postCards, setPostCards] = useState([]);
  const loadingRef = useRef(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [lastAdIndex, setLastAdIndex] = useState(-1);

  const shuffleArray = (array) => {
    const shuffledArray = [...array];
    for (let i = shuffledArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [shuffledArray[i], shuffledArray[j]] = [
        shuffledArray[j],
        shuffledArray[i],
      ];
    }
    return shuffledArray;
  };

  const loadMorePostCards = () => {
    if (!isLoading) {
      setIsLoading(true);
  
      const newPostCard = [...mockData];
      const randomizedNewPostCard = shuffleArray(newPostCard);
      const combinedCards = [...postCards];
      let newAdCards = [];
  
      for (let i = 0; i < randomizedNewPostCard.length; i++) {
        combinedCards.push(randomizedNewPostCard[i]);
  
        if ((i + 1) % 8 === 0) {
          // Insert an ad card after every 8th post
          const adIndex =
            lastAdIndex === adData.length - 1 ? 0 : lastAdIndex + 1;
  
          newAdCards.push(adData[adIndex]);
          setLastAdIndex(adIndex);
        }
      }
  
      // Add new ad cards
      combinedCards.push(...newAdCards);
  
      setPostCards(combinedCards);
  
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const randomizedData = shuffleArray([...mockData, ...adData]);
    setPostCards(randomizedData);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (
        !isLoading &&
        loadingRef.current &&
        window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= loadingRef.current.offsetTop
      ) {
        // Start loading more data when the user reaches the loadingRef
        loadMorePostCards();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [isLoading]);

  const breakpointColumnsObj = {
    default: 4,
    1100: 4,
    700: 3,
    500: 2,
  };

  return (
    <Masonry
      breakpointCols={breakpointColumnsObj}
      className="my-masonry-grid"
      columnClassName="my-masonry-grid_column"
    >
      {postCards.map((item, index) => {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty("buttonType")) {
          // This is an AdCard
          return (
            <Adcard
              key={`ad-${item.id}`}
              title={item.title}
              user={item.user}
              image={item.image}
              buttonType={item.buttonType}
            />
          );
        } else {
          // This is a regular PostCard
          return <PostCard key={item.id} post={item} />;
        }
      })}

      <div ref={loadingRef}></div>9
    </Masonry>
  );
}

export default Foryou;
```

I am expecting infinite scroll for this section with an Adcard after every 8th regular posts/cards, as i have only 5 Adcard data, I want to show them repeatedly just like regular post card.